# WSO2 ESB ISO 8583 Connector Error

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-esb

I have implemented ISO 8583 Connector on WSO2 ESB according to the WSO2 Documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+ISO8583+Connector+Operation

I sent the following XML Message from Rest Client:

```
<ISOMessage>
  <data>
    <field id="0">0200</field>
    <field id="3">568893</field>
    <field id="4">000000020000</field>
    <field id="7">0110563280</field>
    <field id="11">456893</field>
    <field id="44">DFGHT</field>
    <field id="105">ABCDEFGHIJ 9871236548</field>
  </data>
```

I got the following error in the ESB System Log:

```
Couldn't packed ISO8583 Messages    More
TID[-1234] [ESB] [2016-09-07 05:23:28,028] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.connector.ISO8583.ISO8583MessageProducer} - Couldn't packed ISO8583 Messages org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager.readFile(GenericPackager.java:204) org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager.(GenericPackager.java:120) org.wso2.carbon.connector.ISO8583.ISO8583PackagerFactory.getPackager(ISO8583PackagerFactory.java:29) org.wso2.carbon.connector.ISO8583.ISO8583MessageProducer.packedISO8583Message(ISO8583MessageProducer.java:53) org.wso2.carbon.connector.ISO8583.ISO8583MessageProducer.connect(ISO8583MessageProducer.java:39) org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.AbstractConnector.mediate(AbstractConnector.java:32) org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:84) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59) org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:104) org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:148) org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:84) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59) org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:210) org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151) org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please advise for any idea.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Did you Copy the jposdef.xml file into ESB_HOME_Directory as mentioned in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+ISO8583+Connector+Operation

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your case you use inbound for the test-server. If that so, you have to do the following
 1. You can comment the line in the following class, then build the pom and got the new jar and paste it into the lib directory (remove the previous jar from dropins) https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-inbound-iso8583/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/inbound/iso8583/listening/ConnectionRequestHandler.java#L61

2 . Use the following proxy and the following inbound configuration

```
<proxy name="ISO8583_Test" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" transports="https http"> <description/> <target> <inSequence> <ISO8583.init> <serverHost>localhost</serverHost> <serverPort>5000</serverPort> </ISO8583.init> <ISO8583.sendMessage/> <log level="full"/> <respond/> </inSequence> <outSequence> <log/> <send/> </outSequence> </target> </proxy>



<sequence name="request" onError="fault"> <log level="full"/> </sequence>


<inboundEndpoint class="org.wso2.carbon.inbound.iso8583.listening.ISO8583MessageConsumer" name="custom_listener" onError="fault" sequence="request" suspend="false"> <parameters> <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter> <parameter name="inbound.behavior">listening</parameter> <parameter name="port">5000</parameter> </parameters> </inboundEndpoint>
```